# Dynamically replace href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following lines of code in my website - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrzXXe?editors=1000).

What I am trying to do, is make it so that the user must fill in the form first, before downloading an item:

```
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <a href="#example1" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download Item #1</a>

    <a href="#example2" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download Item #2</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I make it so that when the user selects the first or second button on the page, it will send this information to the submit button?

Comment: Thank you to whoever down graded the question .. I'm not too sure why or what your reasoning is, but either way you're not very helpful.

Comment: There might be a few reasons for the downvotes - Your question as-is is a little unclear as to exactly what you want to do.  Secondly, the downvote button tooltip says "this question does not show any research effort" - your question doesn't show how you may have thought about solving this issue so far.

Comment: @JamesThorpe : He probably doesn't know how to get started... which is why I try to help him get started with my answer. From there, he should be able to figure out how to do validation himself...

Answer (score 0):

You add a click handler to your button in JavaScript :

```
var fieldsAreReadyToBeSent = function() {
    // Validation code goes here
    // return true if valid & false if invalid
};

document.querySelector("[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(!fieldsAreReadyToBeSent()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The method `event.preventDefault()` prevents your your form from being submitted if it is considered invalid!

---

### A demo :

```js
var fieldsAreReadyToBeSent = function() {
    return false; // FOR THIS DEMO, ALWAYS RETURN FALSE
};

document.querySelector("[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(!fieldsAreReadyToBeSent()) { // FOR THIS DEMO, THIS IS ALWAYS TRUE
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<a href="#example1" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download Item #1</a>

<a href="#example2" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Download Item #2</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the link in a variable. Then, when the button is clicked, check if the fields are empty (and apply any validation rules). If not empty, apply the submit to the form.

```
$link = 'example.com/download.pdf';

$('.button').click(function(){
    // CHECK THE FIELDS ARE NOT EMPTY
    // APPLY YOUR OWN VALIDATION

    if($field1 = $('.field1').val() != '' && $('.field2').val() != ''){
       // DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO WITH THE LINK
       $('form').submit();
    } 
})
```

On a side note, it's possible that you were down-voted (not by myself) for not providing us with your attempts to solve your own problem. You provided us with your html but not any of your tested logic.